# Datastax Graph: Gremlin query to get all the vertices which does not have a specific edge

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, looker-studio

Gremlin query to return all the vertices which does not have a specific outgoing edge. we have two vertex types which are connected by an edge name" belongs within" now i need to get a vertices which does not have an edge with name "belongswithin"

Answer (score 2):

g.V().hasLabel("suburb").filter(__.not(outE("belongswithin"))).count()